# How to deserialise a external checkpoint manifest in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm using Flink 1.4.2 with incremental checkpoints with RocksDB and saving the checkpoints into a S3 bucket.
The structure of a checkpoint is a manifest file that points to some files that contains the state.
When I open the manifest file in a text editor I see some unreadable chunks and some s3 urls.

How could I deserialise this manifest file in order to get the list of S3 urls?

Answer (score 1):

Both https://github.com/king/bravo and https://github.com/sjwiesman/flink/tree/savepoint-connector contain connectors that can read and write savepoints/checkpoints. You might find one or both useful, either directly, or as an example. See this Jira ticket -- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12047 -- to follow ongoing work to create better tooling for working with Flink snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

The class `SavepointStore` form Apache Flink Runtime Library contains methods to store and load Savepoints.

Just for my current scenario I've created this snippet to retrieve the files related to a checkpoint.

```
import org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.savepoint.Savepoint;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.checkpoint.savepoint.SavepointStore;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.IncrementalKeyedStateHandle;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.KeyGroupsStateHandle;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.StreamStateHandle;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.filesystem.FileStateHandle;
import org.apache.flink.runtime.state.memory.ByteStreamStateHandle;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CheckpointFileLocator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(new CheckpointFileLocator()
                .getS3Locations("/Users/ezequiel/Downloads/chk-3-checkpoint_metadata-f350e54becb2"));
    }

    public Set<String> getS3Locations(String manifestPath) throws IOException {
        Savepoint savepoint = SavepointStore.loadSavepoint(manifestPath, this.getClass().getClassLoader());

        Stream<String> rawStream = savepoint.getOperatorStates().stream()
                .flatMap(operatorState -> operatorState.getSubtaskStates().values().stream())
                .flatMap(operatorSubtaskState -> operatorSubtaskState.getRawKeyedState().stream())
                .map(keyedStateHandle -> (KeyGroupsStateHandle) keyedStateHandle)
                .map(KeyGroupsStateHandle::getDelegateStateHandle)
                .map(this::getPath);

        Stream<String> metadataStream = savepoint.getOperatorStates().stream()
                .flatMap(operatorState -> operatorState.getSubtaskStates().values().stream())
                .flatMap(operatorSubtaskState -> operatorSubtaskState.getManagedKeyedState().stream())
                .map(keyedStateHandle -> (IncrementalKeyedStateHandle) keyedStateHandle)
                .map(IncrementalKeyedStateHandle::getMetaStateHandle)
                .map(this::getPath);

        return Stream.concat(rawStream, metadataStream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    private String getPath(StreamStateHandle streamStateHandle) {
        if (streamStateHandle instanceof FileStateHandle) {
            return ((FileStateHandle) streamStateHandle).getFilePath().toString();
        } else if (streamStateHandle instanceof ByteStreamStateHandle) {
            return ((ByteStreamStateHandle) streamStateHandle).getHandleName();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```